# Hover state is sticky after element is moved out from under the mouse (in all browsers)

Tags: jquery, css, hover

I have a div that shows a series of slides, one at a time. It contains a link at the bottom of the box that triggers the switch to the next slide. When the link is clicked the box shows the next slide and the height of the box changes most of the time.

I have a `:hover` style applied to the link, however once the box's height changes and the link is moved out from under the mouse it keeps its `:hover` state until it is hover again.

I've tried calling `.mouseleave()` and `.mouseenter().mouseleave()` after the change has finished, but it doesn't have any effect. I also created a different `:active` & `:focus` state for the link, which I can see a flash of when the link is clicked, but then it returns to the `:hover`. A `:visited` style has no effect either.

I know there is a common bug in older versions of IE similar to this, but I'm seeing this happen in Chrome and Firefox as well.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/farneman/j4yA7/18/).

Any ideas?

Comment: Some code would be really fine. Just a small test case - ...showcase. THe :hover you are applying is via CSS?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/usocex/edit#javascript,html,live no :hover. Explain a bit better

Comment: @roko It is a css :hover. I'll set up a test case.

Comment: Ok, waiting for the test case

Comment: @roko I've added the test case to my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### *[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/j4yA7/20/)*

The answer is pretty simple.
As we release the mouse click the page jumps to reveal content, so the browser default behav. to register mouseleave and toggle class is missed.

Here are the fixes:

CSS:

```
a:active, a:selected, a:visited { /*  add his to remove stupid dotted outline */
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

jQ1:

```
    $('#prev-page').on('mousedown', function (e) { // use mousedown (some issues with chrome)
        e.preventDefault();
        showPage(pages.index($($(this).attr('href')), 600));
    });
    $('#next-page').on('mousedown', function (e) { // here too!
        e.preventDefault();
        showPage(pages.index($($(this).attr('href'))), 600);
    });
```

jQ2:

```
pages.hide().eq(active).fadeIn(fadeTime, function () {
    // $('#next-page').trigger('mouseleave'); // remove to fix in FF
});
```

Comment: Thanks @roko. Switching from `click` events to `mousedown` events solved the problem. The `.trigger('mouseleave')` was just leftover to show previous attempts at fixing the issue.

Comment: Hm, I have still an issue in Chrome. Trying to fix that too.

Comment: Looks like an issue with Chrome. It cannot handle the click/or/mousedown and fire a mouseleave from an element that disappeared from the click range. Even tried `.blur()` and `.focusout()` but nothing. Let's be clever and create button classes and instead of <a> use <span> and toggle classes on `mouseenter mouseleave` with jQ. Or just add a 'red' class to the `A` element on hover (with jQ). That's it.

Comment: Which version of Chrome are you testing? It's working fine for me with mousedown in Chrome stable and Chrome Canary.

Comment: Chrome 18.0.1025.162 issue: When I click the link is white, but after I re-hover it it won't go back to red again.

Comment: Chrome stable for me is at 18.0.1025.165, see if you can update maybe?

Comment: I'm using Chrome 24.0.1312.52 and this problem still exists. It may not be a clean solution but detaching the link and then appending it to DOM again solves this.

Comment: that removes the highlight "box" on the element -webkit-tap-highlight-color           : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
-webkit-focus-ring-color           : rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);

Answer (score -1):

Toggle the box height by using a CSS class and make sure your hover state exists only for that class.

```
.box {
 height: 0;
}

.box span {
 display: none;
}

.box.open {
 height: 400px;
}

.box.open:hover span {
 display: block;
}
```