# Clear a stuck :hover psuedoclass

Tags: jquery, css, html, webkit

Because of a webkit bug (I think) there is a situation where I have a stuck `:hover` psuedoclass. You can see this here: http://jsfiddle.net/zFk2V/3/

After a drag-and-drop, the previous element stays in `:hover` state in Chrome.
The hover state clears if you hover and mouse away on the stuck item.

I think it should be possible to clear the hover state of elements using event triggering, DOM reflow triggering, or some other shenaniganary.

I have tried:

```
$('[draggable]').trigger('mouseenter')
$('[draggable]').trigger('mousemove')
$('[draggable]').trigger('mouseout')
$('[draggable]').trigger('mouseleave')
$('[draggable]').trigger('blur')
$('[draggable]').trigger('hover')

$('[draggable]').toggleClass('selected')
$('[draggable]').toggleClass('selected') // twice to reset to original

$('[draggable]').height(true) // should trigger a DOM reflow
```

...and different combinations of all of these, with no success

I even tried this, which I was sure would work even though unacceptable:

```
$('[draggable]').hide()
setTimeout(function(){
  $('[draggable]').show()
}, 10)
```

This does not work, either. :(

In all cases, the `:hover` state persists. You can verify this if the chrome inspector and by the visual effect.

I'd love to know if there's a bug filed for this, or if anyone else has heard of it. All I've found is [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946886/hover-sticks-to-element-on-drag-and-drop) talking about it, and that answer is a sledgehammer.

Comment: I added this as a webkit bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=134555. Would love a solution to clear the stuck :hover still though :)

Answer (score 1):

One way around this bug is to use JS `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to apply the hover state instead of the CSS `:hover` pseudo class:

CSS

```
.hover {
    background: #fc9;
}
```

JS

```
lis[i].addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
    this.classList.add("hover");
}, false);
lis[i].addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event) {
    this.classList.remove("hover");
}, false);
```

And to ensure that the hover effect is removed when the drag starts:

```
lis[i].addEventListener("dragstart", function(event) {
    dragged = this;
    this.classList.remove("hover"); // <- Add this
    ol.classList.add("insistent");
}, false);
```

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/36kBp/2/

Comment: That'll work of course, but I have concerns about it--Same answer as here and same concerns: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17953595/111243.  Can you confirm this stuck hover thing is really a bug? You've seen it/had problems with it in the past?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a bug or an intended behavior. It certainly feels like a bug.

I encountered it last week, when animating an element that was hovered. As in your case, when the element moved out from under the cursor Chrome didn't remove the :hover. In my case I could solve it by changing my click event to a mousedown event, and retain the :hover pseudo class. In your case I don't think that solution is applicable.

My 2 cents: I wouldn't get hung up on using JS as a workaround. I imagine it's preferable to having hover events that are never removed?

Comment: FYI here is the Stack Overflow question that solved my :hover issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321275/hover-state-is-sticky-after-element-is-moved-out-from-under-the-mouse-in-all-br